# If $u,v\in \dot H^{1/4}(\mathbb R)$, where does the product $uv$ lie?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u,v\in\dot H^{1/4}(\mathbb R)$. Since by Sobolev embedding $\dot H^{1/4}(\mathbb R)\hookrightarrow L^4(\mathbb R)$, I know that the product $uv$ lies in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, that is, it holds the estimate
$$ \|uv\|_{L^2}\leq C\|u\|_{\dot H^{1/4}}\|v\|_{\dot H^{1/4}}. $$
My question is, is it possible to find a better estimate on $uv$? Does the product lie in some Besov space of positive regularity, or any normed space that is strictly contained in $L^2$?

---

The Sobolev space $\dot H^s(\mathbb R)$ is the space of tempered distributions such that the Fourier transform is locally integrable and the following norm is finite:
$$ \|u\|^2_{\dot H^s}=\left|\int_{\mathbb R}|\xi|^{2s}|\widehat u(\xi)|^2\,d\xi\right|, $$
where $\widehat u$ is the Fourier transform of $u$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I have found an answer. One can use the [Kato-Ponce estimates](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.01294.pdf) in $\mathbb R^n$:
$$ \||\nabla|^s(fg)\|_{L^p} \lesssim \||\nabla|^sf\|_{L^{p_1}} \|g\|_{L^{p_2}}+\|f\|_{L^{q_1}} \||\nabla|^sg\|_{L^{q_2}}, $$
where $p\in[1,\infty]$, $p_j,q_j\in(1,\infty]$ and $s>0$, and where the indices satisfy
$$ \frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{p_1}+\frac{1}{p_2}=\frac{1}{q_1}+\frac{1}{q_2}. $$
One can choose $p=4/3$, $p_1=q_2=2$, $p_2=q_1=4$, $s=1/4$ and obtain (for $n=1$)
$$ \||\partial_x|^{1/4}(fg)\|_{L^{4/3}}\lesssim \||\partial_x|^{1/4}f\|_{L^{2}} \|g\|_{L^{4}}+\|f\|_{L^{4}} \||\partial_x|^{1/4}g\|_{L^{2}}\lesssim \|f\|_{\dot H^{1/4}}\|g\|_{\dot H^{1/4}}. $$
This means that the product of two functions in $\dot H^{1/4}$ lies in the Triebel-Lizorkin space $\dot F_{4/3,2}^{1/4}(\mathbb R)$, and it holds the chain of inclusions
$$ \dot F^{1/4}_{4/3,2}(\mathbb R)\hookrightarrow \dot B^{1/4}_{4/3,2}(\mathbb R)\hookrightarrow L^2(\mathbb R). $$
I am not sure this is the best one can achieve in the Besov/Triebel-Lizorkin scale, so please if anyone has a better answer leve a comment.

---

[These lecture notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ejosephbreen/Lectures_in_Harmonic_Analysis.pdf) contain a proof of the K-P estimates (Theorem 7.10).

Answer (score 0):

You ask about the homogeneous space $\dot{H}^{1/4}(\mathbb{R})$ but let me consider the case of $H^{1/4}(\mathbb{R})$ for the moment.

According to Theorem 7.3 of the paper [Multiplication in Sobolev spaces, revisited](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07379.pdf), if $u, v \in H^{1/4}(\mathbb{R})$, then $uv \in W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R})$ as soon as $\frac 1 2 + s <\frac 1 p$ and $0 \leq s < \frac 1 4$ and $2 \leq p < +\infty$. Unfortunately, these constraints are incompatible.

Of course this does not prove anything, but maybe tends towards the idea that the type of embedding you are looking for will be difficult to obtain since it does not follow from general theorems.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer! I think I have found something anyway, I will post an answer soon.